# Find the general solution of the PDE $z_{xx}+z_{xy}+z_y=z$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the PDE $z_{xx}+z_{xy}+z_y=z$.

By separation of variable method, $z=XY$ gives, $X''-\lambda X'+(\lambda-1)X=0$ and $Y'+\lambda Y=0$.

Case 1. If $\lambda>1$, $X=c_1e^{(\lambda-1)x}+c_2e^x$, $Y=c_3e^{-\lambda y}$ and hence $z$.

Case 2. If $\lambda=1$, $z(x,y)=(A+Be^x)e^{-y}$.

Case 3. If If $\lambda<1$, $X=c_1e^{(\lambda-1)x}+c_2e^x$, $Y=c_3e^{-\lambda y}$ i.e. $z(x,y)=\left(Ae^{(\lambda -1)x}+Be^x\right)e^{-\lambda y}$.

**My question:**

- If this answer correct, should I have to write all three cases? If
  not suggest.
- If the question is solved by canonical form, what would be the answer? (Please solve). Is there any possibility that answers are
  same for both method?
- Is there other suitable method to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: A problem involving a partial differential equation typically has a domain and boundary conditions associated with it. Those tend to clarify, in an approach like yours,  the appropriate simple solutions.

Comment: I think equation for $X$ should be $X''-\lambda X' - (\lambda+1)X=0$.

Comment: @AbolfazlChamanmotlagh Thanks. would you suggest better solution

Comment: I don't know why you divide the problem into cases for different $\lambda$. in all of them $(A e^{(\lambda-1)x}+Be^x)e^{-\lambda y}$ works! also considering the typo i mention in above comment, it should be $(A e^{(\lambda+1)x}+Be^{-x})e^{-\lambda y}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separation of variables is not suitable if there are no boundary conditions. What works is a *change* of variables: let $a=x-y$ and $b=y$, then
$$z_x=z_a,z_y=-z_a+z_b,z_{xx}=z_{aa}$$
$$z_{xy}=z_{aa}a_y+z_{ab}b_y=-z_{aa}+z_{ab}$$
$$z_{xx}+z_{xy}+z_y=z_{ab}-z_a+z_b=z$$
Hence the corresponding linear operator factors, leaving two ODEs:
$$(z_a+z)_b=z_a+z\implies z_a+z=F_1(a)e^b$$
$$e^a(z_a+z)=(ze^a)_a=F_1(a)e^ae^b\implies ze^a=F_2(a)e^b+G_1(b)$$
$$z=e^bF_3(a)+e^{-a}G_1(b)=e^yF_3(x-y)+e^{y-x}G_1(y)$$
$$=e^xF(x-y)+e^{-x}G(y)$$
where the $F$'s and $G$'s are arbitrary functions.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other method to solve

Comment: Can it be solved by canonical method

Comment: Sorry_Canonical form reduction...After the classification of PDE,

Comment: this is indeed the canonical form of this equation. the equation is hyperbolic. so $z_{\xi \eta}-z_{\xi}+z_{\eta}-z=0$ is **the** canonical form. the change in variables as @ParclyTaxel mentioned in his answer are $\xi = x-y$ and $\eta=y$.

Comment: @math131 Since this is hyperbolic, the canonical form would be some variant of the wave equation, but converting to a wave equation and then solving unnecessarily complicates things.